# Long title breaks strict column design on reputation tab

Tags: feature-request, reputation, design, title

On the [reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84?tab=reputation&sort=post) in user profile page when the title is long enough it uses columns that are not intended (in my expectation) to be used for question's title:

> [image]

I propose to place question's title inside the green area in the middle column only.

Comment: @RobertLongson no answer, but turns out already upvoted long time ago.